# Why Matlab K-means does not find the best centroids while Excel Solver does?

Tags: matlab, statistics, k-means, solver, centroid

I have a data set as follows:

Data = [4 12; 5 10; 8 7; 5 3; 5 4; 2 11; 5 4; 3 8; 6 2; 7 4; 10 8; 8 9; 10 9; 10 12]

Then I proceed with:

```
[idx,ctrs, sumD] = kmeans(Data,3)
```

It gives me the centroids and sumD (sums of point-to-centroid distances within cluster) like:

```
ctrs = [5.6000 3.4000; 3.5000 10.2500; 9.2000 9.0000]

sumD = [6.4000; 13.7500; 18.8000]
```

Whereas according to Excel Solver (from a published article), `ctrs` and `sumD` are as follows for k=3:

```
ctrs = [5.21815716 3.66736761; 3.615385665 10.461533; 9.47841197 8.75055345]

sumD = [5.151897802; 7.285383286; 8.573829765]
```

(NB: In that article, the authors give an initial (seed) centroid to each cluster such as  [4 4; 5 12; 10 6] by visual decision from the plot.)

Apparently, Excel finds more accurate `ctrs` values thereby smaller `sumD` values. I could not achieve this with Matlab. That's why I used other parameters of `kmeans` function. I used 'replicates'` and 'options' (MaxIter) and also 'start' parameters - even with 3D array seed - to no avail. I even adopted the same initial seed from the article to Matlab. Followings are what I tried and failed:

**First:**

```
opts = statset('MaxIter',100);
Seed = [4 4; 5 12; 10 6];
[idx,ctrs] = kmeans(Data,3,'Replicates',50,'options',opts,'start',Seed)
```

This gives an error: The third dimension of the 'Start' array must match the 'replicates' parameter value.

**Second:**

I created a 3D array of 50 pages where the first page is the same initial seed above and the rest 49 are random. I created the random pages as:

```
T = rand(3,2,49);
```

After that, I created the 50 pages 3D array like this:

```
Seed2 = cat(3,Seed,T);
```

Then used `kmeans`:

```
[idx,ctrs] = kmeans(Data,3,'Replicates',50,'options',opts,'start',Seed2)
```

However, Matlab gave warnings indicated that all the replicates after the first replication were terminated due to empty cluster created at iteration 1. Also, the idx, ctrs and sumD values obtained were still the same as before - as if I ran my very first function above (i.e. `[idx,ctrs, sumD] = kmeans(Data,3)` ).

I am stuck. I am trying to verify the results of the Excel solver published in the article using Matlab because then I will apply the same algorithm applied on 14 observations from the article to a larger data set of 900+ observations.

What am I doing wrong? What should I correct in my coding to obtain the same or much similar result of the Excel Solver?

Answer (score 1):

The difference appears to be in the choice of the measure of distance used, not in the coding. There is more than one way to define "distance" in this context.

MATLAB uses [squared Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Squared_Euclidean_distance) by default.  By hand calculating this with the MATLAB results I can replicate the `sumD` results you get. However, using squared Euclidean distance measure with the results you give from the paper gives a higher value of `sumD`.

I get the same results for `sumD` as the paper if I use plain (not squared) Euclidean distance.  Using this measure the MATLAB results return higher values for `sumD`.

So neither result is wrong as such, they're just measuring "rightness" in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

How can you be certain that excel values are correct and MATLAB kmeans gives you not so accurate result.

With the quick MATLAB script below, I plotted the centroids, and at least visually it seems correct

```
Data = [4 12; 5 10; 8 7; 5 3; 5 4; 2 11; 5 4; 3 8; 6 2; 7 4; 10 8; 8 9; 10 9; 10 12];

plot(Data(:,1), Data(:,2),'ob','markersize', 10);
axis([min(Data(:,1))-2, max(Data(:,1))+2, min(Data(:,2))-2, max(Data(:,2))+2]);
hold on;

[idx,ctrs, sumD] = kmeans(Data,3);
plot(ctrs(:,1), ctrs(:,2), '*r', 'markersize', 10);
```

[image]

If this is not accurate enough, Instead of trying to customize MATLAB's kmeans, we can define our kmean function. I had implemented the kmeans sometime ago and it seemed easier that asking matlab to fine tune the parameters.

Comment: I guess the OP got a solution with significantly smaller sumD and now wonders why Matlab did not find it. The lower red star for example could be a bit more to the right and below. (just my eye judgement)

Comment: Hi Anoop and Trilarion. Thank you for your answers. Yes, visually the location of the ctrs look similar. Matlab does the clustering same as Excel Solver. However, as Trilarion mentioned, ctrs Matlab finds are not as accurate as Solver, because the sumD value of Solver is smaller (which means better) than Matlab. However, I need accurate ctrs because when I reflect this algorithm to my 900+ data set, there will be many deviations that I can't detect visually, since my data set is large and are very close to each other. So, clustering would be wrong. The link to article is:http://bit.ly/1CmNzBn